# Facebook Integration with Android App Error

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I am trying to integrate **Facebook ** into my android app. I want to implement **like** and **share ** facility on **facebook**. But i am getting error.
[image: Facebook Error]

please help me to solve this.

Also I want to know the process of creating **New App on Facebook.**

I am using code from **GitHub**. My code is -

```
public class MyGreatActivity extends Activity {

    Facebook facebook = new Facebook("333778590046892");

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "offline_access", "publish_stream", "raj21kadam@gmail.com" },
new DialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
             String token=facebook.getAccessToken();  //get access token
//             Toast.makeText(this, "token", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).
                save(token);
            }

            @Override
            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

            @Override
            public void onError(DialogError e) {}

            @Override
            public void onCancel() {}
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        facebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void save(String token){
     Toast.makeText(this, "token"+token, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
     prefs.edit().putString("Token", token).commit();
     }
}
```

I am getting the following error while running the above code -

```
Dialog Errorcom.facebook.android.DialogError: The connection to the server was unsuccessful.
```

Comment: Can you post more information such as the logcat error messages?

Comment: use @JesseChen to notify Jesse.

Comment: Ok @M Mohsin Naeem. Do you have any idea about my post (Facebook Integration)

Comment: `333778590046892` is the App id of your own Facebook App? make sure you have add the your hashkey in your Facebook App...

Comment: @M Mohsin Naeem this is my App ID, I have added hashkey in facebook app.

Comment: @Deepu Did your problem get solved? I am facing the same issue. Can you please help me? Here is my [posted question](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/16011762/getting-error-while-trying-to-login-facebook).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this [Single Sign On (SSO) Using Android Native Client For Facebook](http://facebooksso.blogspot.in/)  .
paste this

```
facebook.authorize(this, new DialogListener() {

@Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
         String token=facebook.getAccessToken();  //get access token
//             Toast.makeText(this, "token", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).
            save(token);
        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {}
    });
}
```

instead of this

```
facebook.authorize(this, new String[] { "offline_access", "publish_stream",   "raj21kadam@gmail.com" },
new DialogListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
         String token=facebook.getAccessToken();  //get access token

        }

        @Override
        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

        @Override
        public void onError(DialogError e) {}

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {}
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi @Tech.Rahul, I have followed the same process which you suggested me, but still I am getting the same error which I had post. Is there any mistake in my code?

Comment: @Deepu : have you seen that blog.. at bottom of the page.. copy that code & put your facebook appID..  hope you have created the all the keys in facebook perfectly..

Comment: I am using same code, also I have created the keys(AppId, Hashkey) in facebook. I hav posted my code it is same as you metioned.

Comment: Ya ok, I m checking. Thanks for your reply

Comment: now I am getting the following error

**08-13 13:29:33.853: E/WindowManager(1457): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.raj.facebookdemo.MyGreatActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@44951630 that was originally added here**

Comment: try this dialog.dismiss(); when your closing or finishing the activity

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15258/discussion-between-deepu-and-tech-rahul)

Comment: I am getting the following error - 

**Dialog Errorcom.facebook.android.DialogError: The connection to the server was unsuccessful.**

Comment: Hi @TechEnd while am integrating facebook  into my android application am getting the following waring .have a look on to this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14729923/android-facebooksharing-integration